# Access an old SQL Compact Edition file with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sql-server-ce

I need to access (only read access) an old SQL Compact Edition 4.0 database file using NodeJS. I have been unable to figure out how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that, but you can use SQL Server Compact Toolbox or a related command line tool (https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox) to move the database to SQL Server (Express), and then connect to the SQL Server instance from node (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/node-js/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-node-js-development?view=sql-server-ver15)